# looking for browser space for iphone

Tags: iphone

whenever user surf internet form iphone the browser share some space of iphone memory now can i access that memory form my app  actually i want to install **SQlite on the fly to my app form web** and next time it can update its own data
plz help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this isn't possible. Applications on the iPhone are sandboxed. Nothing outside of the app can access the app's data. That includes remotely installing apps or updating apps from Safari or any other method.

If you want to put SQLite into your app, you'll have to update your code and then release an update for your app into the app store.